# Problems with unit testing fire base storage

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, firebase-storage

I need to write unit tests for my new function that connects to firebase storage. However i cannot find any documentation anywhere online for how to even mock the database.

Does this work the same way that realtime database testing works?

is it similar to: `var MockFirebase = require("firebase-mock").MockFirebase;`

i need to be able to mock the storage bucket of the database, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tom, please update your request adding the source code you want to test, this will help you get a quicker response.
How do you interact with the database? If you have your service which acts as facade between you application and the data layer, then you might mock it. If you are testing the service itself, is better to see the code to answer